# Ejercicio usando Switch usa siempre default

Tags: c++, c

Buenos dias compañer@s:

Necesito de vuestros sabios consejos. El tema que estoy preparando un poco el temario para 1ºcurso de la Uni (Uned), y a la hora de correrlo me salta directamente al "default", tecleo una cifra y no me devuelve ningún mes.

```
/*Programa que pide un mes por pantalla y te dice los dias que tiene el mes*/
# include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int mes;
    printf("Dame un numero del 1-12 segun el mes \n");
    scanf("%d",&mes);
        switch(mes){
        case'mes==1':
            printf("Enero tiene 31 dias");
            break;
        case'mes==2':
            printf("Febrero tiene 29 dias");
            break;
       
            >
            >
            >
            >
            >
            >
        case'mes==12':
            printf("Diciembre tiene 31 dias");
            break;
         default:
            printf("El formato del mes no es el correcto");
        }

        getch();
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, por pasaros por el hilo. Saludos.

---

Adjunto el aviso que me dá al compilar el ejercicio. Bueno equipo, a ver si puedo seguir adelante con el temario. Muchas gracias.

[image: AVISO WARNING]

Comment: Estoy bastante seguro de que al intentar compilarlo, el compilador o IDE que uses te habrá mostrado algún *aviso* (*warning*). Deberías indicarlo para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Los case están evaluando que mes valga el literal 'mes==1'. En tu caso te interesa evaluar el valor entero, que debería ser 1, 2,.... Por eso tu switch va al valor default siempre. Como curiosidad, si cambiarás el tipo de mes a un array de caracteres, sustituyes el %d por %s y escribes la cadena "mes==1" verás como funciona el primer caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jakala y Juanjo, voy a darle una vuelta a lo que estoy haciendo mal :D

Answer (score 10):

El formato del case es:

```
switch(mes){
    case 1:
        printf("Enero tiene 31 dias");
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Febrero tiene 29 dias");
        break;
    ...
    default:
        printf("El formato del mes no es el correcto");
```

Tienes que poner sólo el valor a comparar, no una expresión.